# How to wait for touch input on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, touches

I am running an animation but I don't want to start the animation until the user touches the screen. I thought of using a loop but that takes a lot of overhead and I couldn't even get it to work for this.

I am aware of the touchesEnded and touchedBegin methods but I am not sure how to use them in this manner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use touchesBegan / Ended in your viewcontroller code and it will trigger when you touch the screen(touchesBegan) or lift your finger off(touches)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//start animation
}
OR
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//startAnimation
}
```

Comment: Oh duh, I didn't think of calling the method inside of the touchesEnded method. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GestureRecognizers are your friend: [Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
[viewToTap addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (void) didTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*) sender {
    // start you animation here
}
```